# Unable to filter result in sql query where two conditions are simultaneously true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a onlineshop `DATABASE` where I have 4 `TABLES` ==> categories, customers, items, orders.

`TABLE` categories ==>

```
+------------+-------------+--------+
| categoryid | title       | status |
+------------+-------------+--------+
|          1 | Electronics |      1 |
|          2 | Books       |      1 |
|          3 | Cloths      |      1 |
+------------+-------------+--------+
```

`TABLE` items ==>

```
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+
| itemid | categoryid | name                                    | price |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+
|      1 |          1 | Android Mobile Phone                    |   250 |
|      2 |          1 | i7 processor 8GB RAM Laptop             |  1000 |
|      3 |          2 | How to train your cat                   |    25 |
|      4 |          2 | Healthy dog food recipes                |    19 |
|      5 |          2 | Learn how to meditate fro mental health |    30 |
|      6 |          3 | Beaautiful Black T-Shirts               |    99 |
|      7 |          3 | Blue Colored Jeans                      |   150 |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+
```

Here I want to filter out *name* from *items* where *category title* is not *Books* and *Cloths*

I am writing the following query to filter out *Books*

```
SELECT name 
  FROM items 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM categories 
        WHERE categories.categoryid = items.categoryid 
          AND categories.title = 'Books');
```

Result -->

```
+-----------------------------+
| name                        |
+-----------------------------+
| Android Mobile Phone        |
| i7 processor 8GB RAM Laptop |
| Beaautiful Black T-Shirts   |
| Blue Colored Jeans          |
+-----------------------------+
```

Now I want to filter out *Cloths* as well such that the the result is -->

```
+-----------------------------+
| name                        |
+-----------------------------+
| Android Mobile Phone        |
| i7 processor 8GB RAM Laptop |
+-----------------------------+
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT i.name 
FROM items i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM categories 
  WHERE categoryid = i.categoryid AND title IN ('Books', 'Cloths')
);
```

or with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM items 
WHERE categoryid NOT IN (
  SELECT categoryid
  FROM categories
  WHERE title IN ('Books', 'Cloths')
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=499ba98a64b3d73c6b74188a3fdcc28b).
Results:

```
> | name                        |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | Android Mobile Phone        |
> | i7 processor 8GB RAM Laptop |
```

Comment: These queries are not equivalent !?!

Comment: Equivalent as what?

Comment: Equivalent to each other.

Comment: They are equivalent for the results they produce. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Or, old school...

```
SELECT i.name
  FROM items i
  LEFT
  JOIN categories c 
    ON c.categoryid = i.categoryid 
   AND c.title IN  ('books','cloths')
 WHERE c.categoryid IS NULL;
```

Comment: With the anti-join pattern (which is my preference) MySQL EXPLAIN will show "NOT EXISTS".  Oddly, EXPLAIN doesn't show "NOT EXISTS" for the query that includes the NOT EXISTS.  +10.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query by using a `join` instead of a subquery and `not exists`, and filter out unwanted categories by name in the `on` clause of the `join`:

```
select i.name 
from items i
inner join categories c
    on  c.categoryid = i.categoryid
    and c.title not in ('Books', 'Cloths')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e86d727323bdc7412d1f48c7ab8c0da7)**:

```
| name                        |
| :-------------------------- |
| Android Mobile Phone        |
| i7 processor 8GB RAM Laptop |
```

Comment: I think it misses the point - as I doubt that this is what the OP was after - but I accept that the data set is simply not thorough enough to be certain... so vote retracted.